# How to determine which application is syncing my desktop folder or remove the sync status?

Tags: windows, onedrive, regedit, owncloud

So, I have a really weird problem:
I recently installed OneDrive for Business on my pc and I tried to sync the desktop and documents folder. OneDrive prompted me an error saying that another program was syncing those folders so it was impossible to proceed with the operation.
I was using Owncloud to sync those folders so I just removed the sync, uninstalled the program, and rebooted the pc.

I've tried again after the reboot but OneDrive kept saying that the desktop folder is still synced by another program (Documents folder now was fine)

So I did some test:

- I've created a new folder called "Desktop2" and moved the position of my desktop there, with this trick I was able to sync the folder (Anyway, I did not confirm the operation )
- Then I've moved the old desktop folder to another location and I've created another folder called Desktop
- Finally, I've restored the position of the desktop on the "Desktop" folder

Now, the weird thing is that OneDrive, after the last step, gives me again the same error.
It's like there is something stuck on windows and it thinks that the folder named Desktop is synced from another application even if is not.

I even have the blue icon for the syncing progress, which is saying that synchronization is suspended

[image: Sync Icons]

Now, there is something that I can do to determine which application is keeping this folder "busy"?
Or, in the alternative, how I can remove the synced status from this folder?

Thank you

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe Mode?